# Moment Matching for a Laplace Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, bayesian-network, kullback-leibler

I have this derivative [image] It belongs to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11327). In the paper, they are trying to model a lightweight bayesian deep neural network by having the distributions on only the activation functions. They use Assumed Density Filtering as a deterministic variation inference method to approximate the distribution of activations. Each activation layer is denoted by Z(i). They choose a gaussian distribution to approximate the posterior at each step. To this end, they try to minimize KL Divergence (KLD). A method of minimization of KLD is moment matching. First and second moments of two distributions, here p and q must be equal. I am trying to assume q as a laplace distribution instead of a gaussian and derive the mentioned derivation. Until now, what I have understood is that the range must be from minus infinity to zero and then from zero to minus infinity. And the rest of steps would be the same. Is this a correct starting point? are there any other changes that will occur when changing the distribution? I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: As I understand, one condition for moment matching to work as a scheme to minimise Kullback-Leibler divergence in context of variational inference is when your variational distribution $q$ belongs to the [*exponential family*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family). This criterion is satisfied in the paper because $q$ is Gaussian. In order for this criterion to be met if you want to use a Laplace distribution for $q$ instead, one check you will need to do is whether the Laplace distribution belongs to an exponential family.

Comment: Yes. That is true and it belongs to the exponential family. The question is that what will be different in this derivation if q was a Laplace distribution instead of a gaussian. In the derivation they are doing here, they are only working with q(z) and it is not parametrized. So, I am not sure how to proceed and derive it for a Lapalce distribution.

Comment: Understood. 1. Unless there is something I have missed from the extract you have supplied, I find it difficult to understand how it is the case that *"q(z) is not parametrized*". In particular, my understanding of variational inference would suggest that $q(z_k)$ in $(27d)$ should really read $q(z_k; \theta)$, where $\theta =\{ \mu, \sigma \}$. 2. When you say you understand that the *"range must be from minus infinity to zero and then from zero to minus infinity"*, is this a query about whether we integrate over $(-\infty, \infty)$ in $\mathbb{E}_q[z_k]$ if $q$ is a Laplace distri?

Comment: Yes, you are right about q (the gaussian distribution in the derivation posted) is parametric. What I meant was that in the derivation, we are working only with q(z) and it is not at any point substituted with the pdf of a gaussian. So, what if I just assume that q(z) is a Laplace instead of a gaussian. Then, how does this derivation change? About your second question, I mean that as a Laplace has a breakpoint on its mean, maybe I need to break down the range as (−∞, u) and then (u, ∞).

Comment: Ah, my apologies for taking so long to understand what you were asking concerning the breakpoints. You are asking whether (and if so, how) we need to amend the derivation to include the fact that the Laplace distribution is defined piece-wise. My lack of familiarity with the Laplace distribution meant I was slow on the uptake. I will include my partial thoughts as an extended comment in the answer box below, otherwise the Stackexchange bot/mods will hound me about discussions in chat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and don't worry. So, basically, I want to do the moment matching for Laplace distribution as q, instead of gaussian as q. I am stuck in the derivation of the derivative above when q is Laplace. My assumption is maybe the breakpoint is what needs to be considered here but I am not sure. I am certain that I can rewrite this derivation for a Laplace but I can't think how to or where to start.

Comment: Because I don't have a concrete answer to this yet, but a good idea of what might be worthwhile looking at and some pointers on where to look, I have created a public chat for this [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126088/moment-matching-and-the-laplace-distribution). That is because in this particular instance, the other queries you have posted on this site might also similarly benefit from these pointers. However, you need to have visited [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). first, otherwise I can't add you to it.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the chat thread. I have been added but there is nothing written there. I am not familiar with chat threads. Should I write down the question there too?